# Bootsstrap calender start date

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar, twitter-bootstrap-3

how to set start date 1 week after?
I'm using this calender  http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/`    var nowTemp = new Date();
    var now = new Date(nowTemp.getFullYear(), nowTemp.getMonth(), nowTemp.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);

```
var checkin = $('#dpd1').datepicker({
onRender: function(date) {
return date.valueOf() < now.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
}
}).on('changeDate', function(ev) {
if (ev.date.valueOf() > checkout.date.valueOf()) {
var newDate = new Date(ev.date)
newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + 1);
checkout.setValue(newDate);
}
checkin.hide();
$('#dpd2')[0].focus();
}).data('datepicker');
var checkout = $('#dpd2').datepicker({
onRender: function(date) {
return date.valueOf() <= checkin.date.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
}
}).on('changeDate', function(ev) {
checkout.hide();
}).data('datepicker');`
```

Comment: Does it not just default to the date of the attached input?

Answer (score -1):

Use this to set the variable "now" to 7 days after the current date:

```
var nowTemp=new Date();
var oneWeekAfter = new Date();
oneWeekAfter.setDate(nowTemp.getDate()+7);
oneWeekAfter.getDate();
var now = new Date(nowTemp.getFullYear(), nowTemp.getMonth(), oneWeekAfter.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: thank you!. itz worked.but still date marker is on current date

Comment: to set the date use `checkin.setValue(now);`

Comment: marker is now placed.but seconds date picker is now visible all date.it is don't disable privies date